# Add space below equations? \belowdisplayskip is not working?

Tags: spacing, align

I use the following code in my LaTex document to specify the space before and after the align-environment (code is before the `\begin{document}`):

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.0cm}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.8cm}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0.0cm}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.8cm}
}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately this is not changing anything?

If I increase the numbers to

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{1.0cm}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{1.5cm}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{1.0cm}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{1.5cm}
}
\makeatother
```

I get the error message

```
! Improper \halign inside $$'s.
<recently read> \halign 

l.138 \end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post an entire MWE (minimum working example) rather than just some code snippets, as it's not clear at the moment if the error message you report is truly related to changing the length parameters you show. By the way, the `amsmath` display math environments (`align`, `gather`, `multline`, etc) don't make use of `\aboveshortdisplayskip` and `\belowshortdisplayskip` at all, hence no need (and no point) manipulating them.

Comment: @Mico It is not possible to post an entire MWE, because my code of my thesis is very long and if I reduce it the error disappears, but in my thesis I need the text, I cannot delete it!

Comment: perhaps you can make an example that includes a preamble (consisting of only the `\documentclass`and the necessary packages and `\newcommand`s), the `align` block that ends on line 138, and the paragraphs that precede and follow that block.  however, you should note that in any document class file, immediately after the definition of `\normalsize`, that command is invoked; since you're changing it, invoking it again at that point would not be a bad idea.  also, the error you're seeing doesn't look like it should have anything to do with your redefinition.  so we need an example.

Comment: It's unlikely to be the cause of the error but your redefinition is incorrect it adds several space tokens to the output, you need a `%` at the end of each line

Comment: You need to make a full working example, your comment about the size doesn't really affect that, just start from a copy and delete everything that you can while still generating the error. If you make an example with just the above code and don't get the error then that indicates that the error is not in this part of the code, so we can't help.